# How to reference DLLs with specific 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: c#, nuget-package

Currently I have a problem installing my Package Nuget, I have a dll that has an x86 and x64 architecture, what happens is that when installing it only adds the x86 reference in my project
I have been trying to add .target and .props files but nothing has worked even when installing it.
[image]

this is my Package Nuget
[image]

this is my .target file
[image]

So I want the x64 and x86 reference to be added to my project when the Nuget Package is installed. I hope I can find some solution

Comment: Don't use $(Platform), use $(PlatformTarget)

Comment: Better IMHO: Resolve the dependency (x86 or x64) at runtime (e.g. using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`)

Comment: I changed it but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is how your problem is solved

```xml
<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Some.Assembly">
        <HintPath>..\packages\......\x64\...............dll</HintPath>
        <Private>true</Private>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Some.Assembly">
        <HintPath>..\packages\......\x86\...............dll</HintPath>
        <Private>true</Private>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

This will also allow for x86 debugging

Comment: Last sentence isn't optional -- you don't want to use a 64-bit DLL for x86 Debug.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. Although, originally I only meant to show the general concept of mutiple platform configuration in a project file, using `when-otherwise`

Comment: I tried to implement it but I still have the same problem

Comment: @HeberAjbal what exactly does not work? I pulled it from the working project file. Make sure you have solution configurations Release/Debug x86/x64. Make sure your projects configured properly

Comment: Both references are not added, only the x86 one

Comment: @HeberAjbal **That is correct behavior.** You will never get both. You should get only one based on the selected build configuration

Comment: oh, I get it, why does this work like that, do you know?

Comment: There is only one scenario when you need to have 2 versions of the same DLL to be loaded. And this is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145293/in-net-6-how-do-i-reference-two-two-versions-of-the-same-nuget-package

In your scenario, you never want to load 2 DLLs. When a vendor supplies x64 and x86 dlls, these meant to go into the build output, for a specific platform. You should be able to develop using either of them. But preferred method is x86. In case of old style Web Projects the x64 tooling is not even available. People debug in x86 and compile for x64 a specific ...

Comment: ... output. So you need to set your proj file XML in such way that depends on what configuration you use during `dotnet publish` or `msbuild` commands, correct reference will be loaded for that configuration. in case of `msbuild` i remember, you can have separate folders with 32/64bit components and point to that specific folder using something like `/references x64/file.dll` <--(not sure if command is exact) to override the project file.